# How to search date in mongodb string format

Tags: mongodb

Please advise how to search in date format in MongoDB

my mongodb data data type is string

```
{ymdhis:"2023-03-14T09:10:37.000+00:00"}
```

The date of that form is stored in the form of a string. How do I retrieve it?

For example, I want to search like this

```
{ymdhis:{'$gte':2023-03-14 00:00:00,'$lte':2023-03-14 23:59:59}}
```

to my javascript code this no results

```
{'todate':{'$toDate':'$ymdhis'}}
{'ymdhis':{'$gte':new Date(new Date('2023-03-14 00:00:00').getTime()+9*3600000)}}
```

how can i get the result

Comment: Would suggest that your DB document to store the date as Date/Timestamp type instead of string. While you may refer to this query for the date conversion and comparison: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7JRuFZKnwzs)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to define a schema:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {type: String, index: true},
  country: {type: String, index: true},
  signup_date: { type : Date, default: Date.now, index: true },
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and then to search:

```js
var User = require('mongoose').model('User');

const mySearch = async () => {
  const time = new Date("March 1 2023").toISOString(); 
  // properly format timestamp for mongodb query
  // "March 1 2023" is an example (or use something like req.body.myTimeVar)

  var myUser = await User.find({country: req.body.country,
    signup_date: {
      $gte: time // $gte: greater than or equal to (also see $lte, $gt, $lt, etc)
    }
  });
}
```